# only long discussions are not welcomed in comments or any kind even if short?

Tags: discussion, support

I saw some moderators deleted a some few comments about God and Islam which were not long discussions. I remember SE says only long discussions are not welcomed and can be moved to chat. 
and SE itself warns when comments become long.

are mods allowed to delete anything based on their personal prefers? or when they delete they should refer to some link explaining the reason of delete?

Comment: Inre [the post](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1480/22) that instigated this question, I had no fundamental problem with your comments; as the other commenter's behaviour was clearly inappropriate, his comments were the ones that needed to be deleted as per site policy.  After they were purged, your own comments were no longer relevant (as the context was no longer there) so they were removed as well.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of this question: [What is fundamentally unique about Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/what-is-fundamentally-unique-about-islam/) the reason for deletion was the non-constructive argumentation of the other user. His comments did not directly engage your answer and were only meant to bait an argument on a tangentially related topic. Also the tone and language were quite offensive. Given all these, I think it was perfectly alright to delete those comments. It's not the length of the discussion per se, it's whether or not it was appropriate.

Comment: "This is not a site for argument and debate." is wrong as I know based on SE messages. SE says LONG discussions in comments are not welcomed. ( that not means should be deleted). the comments there were not long discussion. also such tough moderation make people hate and escape this site. please take it easy and let people come and use this site. deleting comments of people does not make a good feel in them about this Islamic site and even may make hate of Islam. I do not think those comments (even if not welcomed) should have been deleted. no long discussion happened there.

Comment: Some level of argument and debate is OK here - we're not being tough on that at all. In fact, we'd be quite lenient. The issue here is the on-topicness of the comment thread.

Answer (score 2):

SE sites are generally Q&A sites, not discussion sites, any form of discussion and debate is discouraged. Discussion, debate, and arguing are generally not welcome.

Comments are **not** meant for discussions/arguing/providing an alternative perspective. The comments are meant for things like suggestions for improvement, asking clarification about the question, and pointing out problems with an answer.

You can find information about comments [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment):

> **When should I comment?**
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).
>
> **When shouldn't I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of
>     the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing
>     answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing
>     one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!");
>     instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous
>     comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote
>     a better answer if appropriate);
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use
>     chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta
>     instead.