# GoldPseudo is a censor

Tags: support

GoldPseudo censors comments and answers according to personal and radical ideology . He must be removed as moderator. Treat this as a complaint. I am here to learn about Islam. GoldPseudo makes Islam look like medieval nonsense. He interferes with rational debate. Remove his powers.

Comment: I remember writing [Read this before declaring "it's not fair"](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3324/17163) a while back to cover these types of questions.

Answer (score 4):

Islam.SE is a site for objective questions on the teachings of Islam. It is not meant for debate. Nor for expressing your opinions on Islam. Nor are comments meant to go into tangential discussions.

See [Islam—Stack Exchange is not for debates or apologetics](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/) , [Survey of attitudes regarding arguing in comments on StackExchange sites](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/)  and many other posts if you search the meta. If your content disregards this then it should be deleted.

GoldPseudo is a valued member of our community, one of the oldest active users on the site, and an elected moderator. It is rather immature of you to come here and start demanding that he be removed, and that too because he imposed the community's rules on you.

Comment: The first two sentences are paradoxical. Objective questions require debate. Through productive discourse with you, i learnt about islam. But the tyrannical fool GoldPseudo deleted the discourse. YOU are immature if you think debate cannot happen in order to answer questions. Dont take the high horse with me. His job as moderator is to deal with problematic people like me. He is failing.

Comment: And i looked at your link. It is GoldPseudo who is guilty of promoting his ideology. Not me. He is the one in violation of the rules you sent me!!

Comment: And finally. I have said nothing nor cast judgement on any aspect of Islam.